# Matching certain words and characters in a string

Tags: java

Hello again for the 2nd time this night! I'm trying to create an error message if the input for the string does not contain the words/characters: Yes, YES, No, no, Y, y, N, n; and loop back to get the correct input. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! :)

```
do{ 

addAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another salespersons' data?");

if (!addAnother.matches("[YesYESNonoYyNn]"))
    System.out.println("Valid answers: Yes, YES, No, no, Y, y, N, n");
}
while (addAnother.matches("[YesYESNonoYyNn]"));
```

Comment: Tried using regular expression? **"^((yes)|(y)|(no)|(n))$"** by stripping out spaces from boths ends first and then converting the **addAnother** variable to lowercase first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother using regular expressions for this.  Set up a constant that's got all the strings you want to match in a `HashSet` and use `contains`

So outside of all your class's methods, you'll have

```
private static final Set<String> validOptions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Yes", "YES", "No", "no", "Y", "y", "N", "n"));
```

And to validate, you'll just have

```
while (true) {
    addAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another salespersons' data?");

    if (validOptions.contains(addAnother)) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Not a valid option");
}
```

**Update**

There are lots of ways to improve on this, of course.  @blackpen has suggested a couple in comments.  One really good way would be to factor all of this out into a separate method, and actually return true or false to indicate whether the user answered yes or no to the question.  So your class might include all of this.

```
public class GregsFunkyClass {

    private static final Map<String,Boolean> validOptions = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        validOptions.put("yes", true);
        validOptions.put("y", true);
        validOptions.put("no", false);
        validOptions.put("n", false);
    }

    private boolean shouldEnterMoreData() {
        while (true) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another salespersons' data?");
            boolean toReturn = validOptions.get(input.trim().toLowerCase());
            if (toReturn != null) {
                return toReturn;
            }
            System.out.println("Not a valid option");
        } 
    }
}
```

Then you can call this method from some other method in your class and actually get the answer you were looking for.  Here, the `trim()` call removes leading and trailing whitespace, and the `toLowerCase()` call makes a mixed case or upper case input match the values that we've actually put in the map.

**Note** - you're doing something a bit strange, mixing up console output with GUI input.  Typically, an application is either a GUI or a console application, but not a hybrid.  You might want to actually output the error message in a wee popup, rather than on the console, if the user types a wrong option.  I haven't done that here, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Good one. Yeah, probably way easier than regular expressions. But, watch out if the user enters leading/trailing spaces ... and also if he uses mixed case letters.

Comment: And may be you also want to lower-case all the elements of the hash as well as lower-case the user's input, so that they will match exactly?

Comment: But, I guess you still want to handle mixed-case typing (YeS, nO)? Yes, OP eventually needs to check for both postitive (yes) and negative (no). Because, on positive, he loops; on negative, he quits.

Comment: The entire program is supposed to loop back around and I can go through and enter it again. However, I'm stuck again. Now I need my last while / do while loop to only contain the yes values. *EDIT* I made another hashset with only the yes values and it works! Thank you @DavidWallace

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @David's nice answer, just in case, if you still want to use regular expressions (inefficient?), here is how you can do that too:

```
public class Main {

     public static boolean isYes(String str) {
        String s1=str.trim();
        return(s1.matches("(?i:^((yes)|(y))$)"));
     }

     public static boolean isNo(String str) {
        String s1=str.trim(); 
        return(s1.matches("(?i:^((no)|(n))$)"));
     }

     public static void main(String []args) {

        System.out.println(isYes(" yes "));
        System.out.println(isYes("  yEs  "));
        System.out.println(isYes("  y"));

        System.out.println(isNo(" yes "));
        System.out.println(isNo("  yEs  "));
        System.out.println(isNo("  y"));

        //--------------------------------

        System.out.println(isNo(" NO "));
        System.out.println(isNo("  no   "));
        System.out.println(isNo("n   "));

        System.out.println(isYes(" NO "));
        System.out.println(isYes("  no   "));
        System.out.println(isYes("n   "));

     }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
true
true
true
false
false
false
```